# Am I in danger using this lithium polymer 3S 11.1V battery?

Tags: lipo

I have an odd problem (to me, at least), and I really need some advice before tossing $40 to the recycler, as well as for my own personal safety and knowledge.

I'm building a robot, and in fact have built a couple using this battery - all well and good. But somehow I managed to drain it to around +/-8V, and my charger laughed at me when I tried charging it.

After a bit of forum reading, I don't have a NiCad charger, or trickle charger, so I opted to take another piece of advice I read - just let it sit overnight.  So I did.  This morning, it tested at 10.1V - I was quite surprised already!

Thinking it might be my lucky day, I hooked it up to the charger, and after 10 mins, checked it for warmth (nothing) and tested it at 10.4V so it seemed to be charging.

After awhile, and periodically checking it for heat (never any: not on wires, connectors, battery, nor charger), I thought I would test it again, and UH OH - 12.2 volts!  With all the horror stories I've heard, and only being a 2-year hobbyist, I dropped it on my desk and carefully finger-probed it for heat / soft spots.  Nothing.

Is this battery a dangerous bomb?  It seems the over-drain killed the over-charge protection. I dunno, I just think maybe I'm better off tossing it, but ya, 40 bucks is 40 bucks.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that is not normal? What do you expect a fully charged LiPo cell to measure?

Comment: Which charger (brand/model) do you have?

Comment: Just because you mention other charger types, be aware that yes, lithium ion batteries are quite dangerous when mistreated, and you should *never* charge one without a charge circuit specifically designed for that chemistry, and *never* discharge one without overcurrent and overdischarge protection.

Comment: As noted by others, Vfullchg = 12.6V. | Vminn_advisable is around 9V but 7.5V is unwise but unlikely to cause major damage. YMMV

Comment: thanks for the feedback everyone... I get that 12.xV is not a major issue, but my concern is that it let itself charge that high in the first place.  Wouldn't that indicate the over/under charge circuit is fried, and the safest bet is to toss it?   Or do you think its safe to go ahead and use it, and continue to charge it?   I guess what freaks me out is had I not unplugged it from charger to test out of curiousity, would it have continued to charge until it burst?

Comment: Well we don't know if your pack contains overcharge protection or not. And like I explained in my answer already, 11.1V is the nominal average voltage that is printed on the battery, not the max voltage, and cells are charged to 12.6V to fully charge them. They will not stop charging at 11.1V even if they have overcharge protection.

Comment: oh, thats good to know, Justme, thank you - I get it now!  I was just being paranoid when I saw it charged to 12.2v - I will give it a try and just keep fingers crossed it doesn't blow up!  lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 11.1V or 3.7V per cell is the nominal voltage. It will be less when drained, and more when fully charged.

A fully charged cell should be about 4.2V per cell or 12.6V.

The battery voltage is not too high.

But we cannot know if it has had any damage that would make it simply lose some capacity or if it has also become dangerous if it was overdischarged to 8V, or 2.67V per cell.

Comment: yes, its a 11.1v pack... so you're saying the fact that it charged up to 12.2v is ok - I get that, but shouldn't I be concerned that it didn't stop itself from charging at 11.1v, indicating perhaps the overcharge circuit is fried?

Comment: 11.1V is a nominal average of voltage that is printed on pack, and to fully charge the cells the pack is charged up to about 12.6V.